# Why is google storage api working with java and not php?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client, google-api-java-client, google-api-client

I've tried both samples:

- For Java, using gcloud auth login is enough to let my app connect to the storage and i can retrieve the content of the bucket.
- For Php, it doesn't work, it still tells me that there is a problem with the credentials, so i can't retrieve the content of the bucket.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples

I've done exactly what's written in the docs, I have the rights to read obviously since it works for java.

P.S : I'm workng localhost.

EDIT 1 :

```
Host: localhost Connection: keep-alive Accept: 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8 
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ja;q=0.2 Cookie: gsScrollPos=0; 
JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; PHPSESSID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX yes I installed composer as specified. the error : Could not load the default credentials
```

I'll try comparing the request.

Comment: You might want to check the headers, could you dump both requests including body and headers here? I think it might be something like `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` And you didn't forgot to install `composer` as specified in the docs?

Comment: a) why not `edit your question` 
b) you should `compare` the request in java and php
c) try to recreate it in `Postman` first https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Could you use wireshark or a similar tool to check exactly what HTTP request you're sending from Java, and which one from PHP? Then if that doesn't explain things to your satisfaction please edit your Q to show the wireshark (or whatever) output in each case.